# how to set input fields side by side using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

input fields are shown side by side like four fields mobile and email and name and location using only JavaScript or jquery

Comment: Its not JavaScript or jQuery, you need to use CSS for this kind of alignment. Have a look at the CSS property "float". You will need to use a common class for all these elements like this: `<style>.myfield {float:left; padding:5px}</style>`  Add this to your page and then for all these fields use it like this: `<input name='email' class='myfield'/>` Better still try to use some standard framework like boostrap. Google for details

Comment: You want to create inputs with JS or they already in HTML?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is not clear.  Please elaborate on what you are trying to ask, including a [mcve] demonstrating what you've tried and what isn't working as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

inputs should be showing side by side as default as far as I'm aware. it would also depend on what you're layout is looking like now. Below is just some very basic HTML that I threw in without any CSS or Javascript and they all show side by side.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="div">
        <input type="text" name="" id="">
        <input type="text" name="" id="">
        <input type="text" name="" id="">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```